# Call html partial from different folder C#

Tags: c#

I have the following DIR structure:

```
Public
--mobile
----Views
------UK
--------Recipes
----------ViewRecipePlain.cshtml // pull this
--mobilePublic
----Views
------UK
--------Recipes
----------ViewRecipe.cshtml // into this
```

I want to call `ViewRecipePlain.cshtml` from within `ViewRecipe.cshtml`

Inside ViewRecipe.cshtml I'm trying:

```
@Html.Partial("../../../../mobile/Views/UK/Recipes/ViewRecipePlain")
```

But am getting the error:

```
Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.
```

Is there another way to do this?

**UPDATE**

I also tried:

```
@Html.Partial("~/mobile/Views/UK/Recipes/ViewRecipePlain.cshtml")
```

But get the following error:

```
The partial view '~/mobile/Views/UK/Recipes/ViewRecipePlain.cshtml' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. 
The following locations were searched:
~/mobile/Views/UK/Recipes/ViewRecipePlain.cshtml
```

Have also update DIR structure to be more accurate if it makes a difference but doubt it does.

Comment: Is the switching between "Main" and "Plain" after ViewRecipe intentional or  a typo? Because you said you're trying to call "ViewRecipeMain" but all of your paths say "ViewRecipePlain".

Comment: Thanks Sean, it was indeed a typo, fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the absolute path of the view:

```
@Html.Partial("~/mobile/Views/UK/Recipes/ViewRecipePlain.cshtml")
```

Comment: You should add the file extension too (look more carefully at the answer)

Comment: Note that the .cshtml extension is necessary when calling the view with a path.

Comment: Exactly same fail when adding extension but thanks for the heads up on that

Comment: I actually think there might be other forces at work preventing this but I'll accept this answer as it's correct, and I think the question might have some meaning down the line.

Comment: Hm, thats strange. Can you post the whole project structure beginning from the root folder where the .csproj file is?